# facebook share with customization...almost working, how do I {{ request.build_absolute_uri }}(->this shows url I'm in) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm trying to customize facebook share. I'm using this fantastic app;https://github.com/kni-labs/rrssb to do this. I tried meta tags facebook provide, and it's not working for me. but with java-script, it kinda works.

```
<ul class="rrssb-buttons clearfix">

  <li class="rrssb-facebook">

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}" class="popup">facebook-share</a>
</li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('.rrssb-buttons').rrssb({
    // required:
    title: 'email',
    url: 'http://www.reddit.com/',

  });
});
</script>
```

this shows the picture of reddit, description of reddit, etc.. 
so I thought I should put the domain user is trying to share in url instead of reddit url. I googled around, and I saw how some people post images and description in url...so my question is how do I put the url user is trying to share in the url? how do I put image there?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.location.href` as URL to use current page's URL. To specify image you just need to add `image` key when initializing `rrssb`. As if you see source code of `rrssb.js` you will see what parameters it supports when initializing. Which are

```
// Settings that $.rrssb() will accept.
var settings = $.extend({
    description: undefined,
    emailAddress: undefined,
    emailBody: undefined,
    emailSubject: undefined,
    image: undefined,
    title: undefined,
    url: undefined
}, options );
```

So your code will change to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.rrssb-buttons').rrssb({
    title: 'email',
    url: window.location.href,
    image: your_image_url
  });
});
```

**Edit (Only URL is being used not image):**

I don't think that you can use image for facebook or twitter. As if you see source code of [`rrssb.js`](https://github.com/kni-labs/rrssb/blob/master/js/rrssb.js#L59) you will see that only URL is shared to facebook. URL and description are shared to twitter. So some of the settings are shared to some of the social sites.

Also in the `readme.md` of the `rrssb.js` if you see facebook sharing example

```
<li class="rrssb-facebook">
    <!--  Replace with your URL. For best results, make sure you page has the proper FB Open Graph tags in header: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/ -->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://kurtnoble.com/labs/rrssb/index.html" class="popup">
      <span class="rrssb-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 29 29"><path d="M26.4 0H2.6C1.714 0 0 1.715 0 2.6v23.8c0 .884 1.715 2.6 2.6 2.6h12.393V17.988h-3.996v-3.98h3.997v-3.062c0-3.746 2.835-5.97 6.177-5.97 1.6 0 2.444.173 2.845.226v3.792H21.18c-1.817 0-2.156.9-2.156 2.168v2.847h5.045l-.66 3.978h-4.386V29H26.4c.884 0 2.6-1.716 2.6-2.6V2.6c0-.885-1.716-2.6-2.6-2.6z"/></svg></span>
      <span class="rrssb-text">facebook</span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

in the comment you can see stated that

> For best results, make sure you page has the proper FB Open Graph tags
>   in header

Which means, facebook will pick image information from FB Open Graph meta tags of the header section of the page.

Comment: thank you very much but even when when I set title and description, just default url shows up....can you please help me..?

Comment: for image I want to do {{post.image}}, how do I bring the image post has for javascript?

Comment: @emfour are you using only facebook share are all of the social shares?

Comment: I use facebook  share and twitter tweet

Comment: hmm is there a way to do {{post.image}} and {{post.description}} inside my <script> tags?this task is harder than I expected...or am I just approaching it wrong?

Comment: @emfour you can do `{
    title: 'email',
    description: {{post.description}}
    url: window.location.href,
    image: {{post.image}}
  }` but see me edited answer first.

Comment: yeah that's what I'm doing but it's not working...it just shows the url...I want to do titiel:{{post.title}} and descritpiton {{post.descriptipin}}....is there a way to do ti?

Comment: hmmm not working....I don't have any face book meta tag...is that the reason maybe?

Comment: Yes you will need to use post.image and post.description in the meta tags instead of putting here in rrssb.js for facebook to consider these.

Comment: See the link given in the comment athttps://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/

Comment: yes I read that link multiple times but things didn't work that I'm using this approach....

Comment: dang...meta property tag isn't working...can you please help me out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107816/discussion-between-em-four-and-muhammad-tahir).